# How to use three conditions in WHERE clause of mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my current MySQL syntax (but this doesn't work):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userID = $userID AND postBy = $postBy AND postType = 'unread'
```

Here is the picture of my MySQL table (a picture can show more than words!)

[image]

I want to know if there is any other way of doing it or if I have to forget this idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you're attempting to do, it's just that you haven't quoted the PHP variable

Make sure you're escaping/sanitizing your input. Also use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) if possible

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userID = $userID AND postBy = '{$postBy}' AND postType = 'unread'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really use parameters, but other than that you will need to enclose the text variables in single quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userID = $userID AND postBy = '$postBy' AND postType = 'unread'
```